# Use solution-wide resources with WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, embedded-resource

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution, which is split in several C#-WinForm applications.

To have a similar user interface I put all the icons/pictures into one project (ResourceProject) and marked the resource file public.

By directly editing the .Designer-file of a Form I can now explicitly assign the Image to something from the resource file of the ResourceProject by stating

```
button1.Image = ResourceProject.Properties.Resources.DemoPic
```

However, from time to time, the designer overwrites this with

```
button1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)resources.GetObject("button1.Image")));
```

and creates a local resource file, which has the image embedded.

This is exactly what I wanted to avoid in the first place, since I might want to alter easily some icons later on and have those changes directly spread over all projects.

The only way to avoid it seems to be to assign the images not in the Designer file but in some other method in the actual form file.

Is there any other way around this problem?

Comment: You really need to avoid touching the Form's Designer: it's not yours to handle. Avoid the PropertyGrid if you use resources that do not directly belong to the project. Assign the shared resources in the Form's constructor. Building a resource-only `dll` is another option.

Comment: This is likely to happen when the assignment runs at design-time as well.  Use the DesignMode property to prevent it from executing.

Comment: You should not change designer.cs file, it's auto-generated and any any change which you make in that file will be replaced with auto-generated code the next time which you change something in the form.

Comment: Sharing resources with design-time support without changing designer file is possible by following the steps which I shared in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not change designer.cs file, it's auto-generated and any change which you make in the file will be replaced with auto-generated code the next time which you change something in the form.

But to share image resources between multiple projects in a solution with design-time support, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a class library project, let's call it `ResourceLibrary`.
2. Add a `Resx` resource file to the root folder of the project with this name `Resources.Resx`.
3. Open the resource designer and change its *Access Modifier* to `Public`. (It will set its *Custom Tool* to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`)
4. Add a few images to the resource designer and save it.

Then in the Windows forms project do the following settings:

1. Add a reference to `ResourceLibrary`.
2. Right click on windows forms project and choose *Add* → *Existing item...*
3. Browse to the `ResourceLibrary` folder and choose `Resources.Resx` file.
4. Click on drop-down arrow of the Open button, and choose ***Add As Link***.
5. Select `Resource.Resx` which has added to windows forms project and choose properties.
6. Set its *Build Action* to `None`
7. Set its *Custom Tool* to a text like `None`
8. Set its *Custom Tool Namespace* to the namespace of the resource in the other assembly: `ResourceLibrary`.
9. Rebuild the project.

Then for all the image properties you can choose the other resource file from drop-down in the *Select Resource* dialog. The code generation will generate correct code for the property and you have a correct build and it works as expected at design-time as well as run-time.

You can clone or download a working example here:

- [Repository](https://github.com/r-aghaei/SharedResourcesExample)
- [Download](https://github.com/r-aghaei/SharedResourcesExample/archive/master.zip)

Comment: Impressive, it actually works, thanks a lot! One note: It seems to be actually important, that the Resource file is in the root folder of the ResourceLibrary-project, not in a subfolder with a subnamespace. Otherwise, the namespace in the designer will not be set correctly.

Comment: You're welcome. If you add `Resource1.resx` to `Folder1` in `ResourceLibrary` project, then you can still add link of `Resource1.resx` to root of windows forms project, just make sure you set the `Custom Tool Namespace` of the link in your windows forms project to `ResourceLibrary.Folder1`.